# Issue with release pipeline: Powershell script is not running in the working directory specified

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

In my release pipeline, I have specified the working directory for the powershell under the advanced options as `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_{project name}`

[image: working directory]

However, when the powershell script ran, the working directory of the script is `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`

Any attempt to change the working directory in the powershell script resulted in an error

> "Cannot find path 'D:\a\r1\a_{project name}' because it does not
> exist".

Note: My artifact was downloaded from this path so it should exist.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path "**`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`**" is the installation directory of '**`powershell.exe`**' on the agent machine. It should not be the default working directory of the PowerShell task.

On the Microsoft-hosted Windows agents, normally '**`$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`**' should be "**`D:\a\r1\a`**", and "**`$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_{project name}`**" should be "**`D:\a\r1\a\_{project name}`**" not "**`D:\a\r1\a_{project name}`**".

It seemed did not correctly combine the path string for the specified working directory. A slash (**`\`**) was missed that caused the system can't find the path.

You can try to change "**`$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_{project name}`**" to "**`$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\_{project name}`**" to see if it can work. Or try other agents.

However, I tested on my side and everything is working fine. The specified working directory can be correctly recognized.

- **PowerShell Tasks**
  [image]

  [image]
- **Results:**
  [image]

  [image]